# "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist error" while I try to deal with chrome extensions problem

Tags: python, robotframework

First problem: when I run my Robot Framework code in Chrome there is popup:
"loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator".
I try disable extensions of chrome driver by using code:

I try disable extensions of chrome driver by using code I've found online.

```
[Arguments]    ${URL}
${options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --no-sandbox
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    test-type
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --start-maximized
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --disable-dev-shm-usage
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --enable-automation
Call Method    ${options}    add_argument    --disable-extensions
Create Webdriver    Chrome   chrome_options=${options}
Go To    ${URL}
```

But when I'm using this I've got problem: chrome starts without popup but there is error:
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

When I comment argument --disable-extensions browser start fine but returns popup "loading of unpacked extensions is disabled by the administrator"

Answer (score 0):

Found IT

Helped me adding:
Call Method       ${options}    add_experimental_option      useAutomationExtension    ${FALSE}

to the parameters